# Why is numpy.array much slower than PixelAccess?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I was trying to improve a simple program using numpy matrixes rather than Image.PixelAccess but some simple test is like 4 times slower.
Is this normal? Online discussion and tutorial enforce numpy's speed.
Imagine this test:

```
img = Image.open('whatever')
height = img.height
width = img.width
img = img.convert('RGBA')
matrix2 = np.asarray(img, dtype=np.uint8)
t1 = perf_counter()
for point in ( (x, y) for x in range(0, width) for y in range(0, height) ):
    matrix2[point][:]= np.array([255, 255, 0, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
t2 = perf_counter()
```

If I switch the matrix2 per matrix, of PixelAccess class

```
img = Image.open('whatever')
height = img.height
width = img.width
img = img.convert('RGBA')
matrix = img.load()
t1 = perf_counter()
for point in ( (x, y) for x in range(0, width) for y in range(0, height) ):
    matrix[point]= (255, 255, 0, 255)
t2 = perf_counter()
```

This is much faster.
I could make the np.array that I insert a constant, and the speed is enhanced.
But in the future, I want to insert some np.array that is not the same at every iteration.

Comment: I don't know anything about the PixelAccess, but it's well known that indexing like this of `numpy` arrays is slow.

Comment: If I access contiguous elements, isn't it fast?
Doing something like matrix2[point][3] = 255 is also slow

Comment: This problem is similar to the one I just answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665939/what-is-fastest-way-to-read-files-line-by-line/69681179#69681179). However, in you case, you can/should *vectorize* the code. Moreover, please note that the `np.array` is recreated in each iteration from the constant list. The CPython *interpreter* does not perform any (advanced) optimizations. Note that both code are pretty slow regarding the computation.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, be careful when recommending "vectorize", since beginners often don't understand what that means in a `numpy` context.  Also I think your other answer is a bit involved for this user, and deals with a io bound task, not image pixel assignments.

Comment: Setting blocks of 4 values is faster than setting each one with a call, but I imagine your `x,y` are ranging over hundreds of values, e.g. (400,600), that 240000 calls to the indexing operation.